Is it possible to add custom Social Media accounts to contacts in the Contacts app?
I wanted to add a contact's Reddit username to their contact card. However, it seems like I couldn't find "Reddit" under the list of custom fields. Below are the only fields I could see. Is it possible to add a Reddit username there?


Is that screenshot from iOS or macOS? I What is your iPhone and which iOS is installed on it? What is your Mac and which macOS is installed on it?

The question claims to be about iOS, but that looks like a Mac screenshot. iOS doesn't use side-by-side (-) and (+) buttons.

On iOS, you can add a custom service (screenshot is from an iPad, but it works the same on the iPhone).

